# How to convert bokeh plots to BytesIO object to encode the plot with base64 module

Tags: base64, python-3.6, bokeh, bytesio

I have a `plot` object of `bokeh` where I plot `sin(x)` curve.

```
from math import *
from io import BytesIO
from bokeh.plotting import (figure, output_file, show)
from bokeh.io import (export_png, export_svgs)

import base64
import numpy as np

plot = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500)

x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.array([sin(i) for i in x])

plot.line(x, y, line_width=1)
```

Now, instead of saving it to some `html` file by some name, `output_file('sine.html')` I want to create a `BytesIO()` object so that I can further do `base64` encoding.

I kindly need community help.

The reason why I desire is in `matplotlib` I can export an image as `BytesIO()` object and work with it smoothly rendering it back in `Flask` or `Dash` app like this,

```
figfile = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')
plt.clf()
figfile.seek(0)
figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())
return figdata_png.decode('UTF-8')
```

and I want the same applicability with `bokeh`.

Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Bokeh provides this functionality in [`bokeh.io.export.get_screenshot_as_png`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.export.get_screenshot_as_png):

```
from bokeh.io.export import get_screenshot_as_png

img = get_screenshot_as_png(plot)
```

`img` is a PIL image instance which contains the image.

Off-topic: This can also be used to have the plot displayed as a PNG in JupyterLab. Just call `get_screenshot_as_png(plot)` and you are done.